# How many potential buckets are there in a JavaScript object when it's created, and does this change as the number of entries in the object grows?

Tags: javascript, object, hashtable, big-o

I'm trying to better understand how the space and time complexity of reading and writing values changes as the number of entries in an object grows.

Comment: That's likely an implementation-specific detail.

Comment: Is the decision of whether to grow the key space as the number of entries grows also implementation-specific?

Comment: I'd have thought so, but I haven't read the ECMA specification.

Comment: It depends on the implementation. Your question seems to originate from Java's use of buckets, which you don't find in C# for example. V8 uses hidden classes: 

https://www.quora.com/Are-JavaScript-Objects-implemented-as-HashTables-Is-key-value-access-O-1